# Which redis method is better: calling HSET multiple times or calling HMSET once?

Tags: python, redis

I have a list of ids. For each id, I do a web request, which returns the name associated with the id. Then this key/value (id/name) pair is added to a dictionary. Once this is done, I add the dictionary to redis using hmset.

I'm wondering if it would be better to simply add each key/value pair to redis right after each request.

I think it comes down to this: which is more costly, multiple calls to redis, or the extra memory usage of storing the values in a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, when working with Redis and optimizing for performance, it's preferable to save trips to the network rather than bytes of memory.

Redis stores data very [efficiently](http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization).  If you run the `INFO MEMORY` command in a redis-cli session you'll see just how little memory is being used.

Latency can impact responsiveness, which is why you normally want to take advantage of pipelining where possible.  Marc Gravell [illustrates](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/PipelinesMultiplexers.md) this well when explaining his C# API for Redis.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I think that there isn't simple answer to that - it depends on constraints that you actually have and how you calculate cost of such processing. In some cases memory is more valuable than processing time in other cases it's the opposite.

First - make sure if you have to worry about such optimisation at all. Maybe you just could choose method that is most convenient for you and it will be enough.

In most cases request to Redis is so fast (comparing to HTTP request) that its time can be negligible.

Depending on how big your key/val pair is, cost of writing this data to redis also might be so high that overhead of request will be negligible.

Anyway, If it's not enough then take into account constraints that you might have. E.g.:

- how much memory your script can use during processing?
- how quickly corresponding key/val should be present in redis after making HTTP request?
- how many requests/sec your redis server can handle?

Also notice, that using `HMSET` will make your code more complicated and it'll require more effort to write such script.

Answer (score 0):

Your routine will init Redis DB. 
As I ever say, do not think of optimisation in the first place. Do something simple to understand and to maintain as this script is a kind of init Redis DB.
For this reason, go for HSET.

If you ever face a performance/runtime problem, you can change this code easily, because it was easy to write. :)

I suggest you keep track of key that you are using in redis, because your DB can realy become messy after som time of use.

Do not think of memory footprint at first, Redis do manage that very well for you. (see [Redis FAQ](http://redis.io/topics/faq)